# Llamar a función externa desde un archivo js ya cargado previamente

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente código en un archivo index cualquiera:

```
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Script con la función que necesito -->
    <script src="assets/dist/js/home.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Todo el código de la página -->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Llamo a la función alojada en home.js
        var ax = tableFn(param1, param2);
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Y luego, mi archivo home.js

```
$ (function () {
    function tableFn(param1, param2) {
        // Lineas de código de la función
    }
});
```

Mi problema es que no logro que la función se ejecute. Hice una prueba colocando cualquier palabra fuera del bloque del archivo home.js, como lo siguiente:

```
palabra;
$ (function () {
    function tableFn(param1, param2) {
        // Lineas de código de la función
    }
});
```

Lo que me arrojó el siguiente error en la consola:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: palabra is not defined at home.js.
```

Lo cual se entiende perfectamente, ya que agregué un código no válido en el archivo home.js. Esto también me indica que el archivo home.js sí se carga junto con el html, ya que de lo contrario no me arrojaría ese error.

Cual puede ser el error? Porque ejecutando el código, desde la consola me arroja el siguiente error que ocurre en el html:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: tableFn is not defined at index.
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLUCIONADO

Algo tan simple no lo pude notar. Es quitar la función "fuera" del $ (function() {}), es decir

```
function tableFn(param1, param2) {
    // Lineas de código de la función
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ (function () {
function tableFn(param1, param2) {
    // Lineas de código de la función
}
```

});

Debes eliminar la Funcion padre dejando unicamente la funcion tablefn